# winForms, referencing to a text box and button from a class

Tags: c#, winforms, class

I really need help with referencing from a class to a text box and button on a form using the declared names of the boxes and buttons.

example:

say you have a box called testBox that is located in Form1
i am in the testingBox Class and i need to write:

```
testBox.AppendText("Test Box");
```

but the syntax error is: "The name 'testBox' does not exist in the current context"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the controls to your class using constructor parameters and private fields.

Comment: Or you can pass the controls collection and do a name lookup.